# Is there a way to delete commas between arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a quiz which prints a list of clubs based on the user's answers. When I run it, however, there's a comma between each array which I don't want.

I tried to delete the commas but they are necessary between each item for the code to work.

I have this list:
`var clubs=[[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical", ""],["Student Government", ""],["Tricorn", ""],["FBLA", ""]...] //and it continues`

and then this function to print them:

```
function eliminateClubs(){
for(h=0;h<=personChoices.length;h++){
   if (personChoices[h]==1){
     recClubs.push(clubs[h].join(', <br/>'));
   }
 }
}
```

When it prints it looks like:

```
Fall Production,
Spring Musical,
, Student Government,
, Tricorn,
, FBLA,
etc...
```

I don't know how to get rid of the commas that appear before each different array, but the ones after each item are fine.

Comment: In your join statement, you're adding the comma in... `clubs[h].join('<br />')` the join() lets you define what you want represented between array elements when they're flattened out into a single element

Comment: When you call `join` on `["Tricorn", ""]` it's going to result in `Tricorn, ,` because you have an empty value...

Comment: good catch @HereticMonkey

Comment: I'd just flatten and filter the "empty" values: `clubs.flat().filter(Boolean)`

Comment: how are you controlling the "print" part of your code? if you're not doing another join on `recClubs` then I think commas may come naturally when JS tries to print out an array.

Comment: One possible solution is to replace `recClubs.push(clubs[h].join(', <br/>'));` by `recClubs.push(clubs[h].filter(Boolean).join(', <br/>'));`

Comment: @HereticMonkey the extra comma is there with it or without. I put the empty value because sometimes it wouldn't break without it.

Comment: @Doug I'm just using `document.getElementById("recClubs").innerHTML= recClubs; ` to print it. Is there another way that would get rid of the automatic commas?

Comment: @Cliodhna check out this sample on codepen: https://codepen.io/doughensel/pen/PvReeK -- when an array tries to print out without a join statement (in your code the `recClubs`) it will automatically add commas between array elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
function eliminateClubs(){
 for(h=0;h<=personChoices.length;h++){
   if (personChoices[h]==1){
       if (clubs[h].indexOf(',') > -1)
       {
          clubs[h] = clubs[h].replace(',','');
       }
     recClubs.push(clubs[h].join(', <br/>'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, except for a trailing comma at the end of the list in the last string.

Comment: The question asked to remove only the commas before each different array and the solution does that.

Comment: Hard to argue with that reasoning.

Comment: When I added this to that function it didn't change anything, but it looks like it should work

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing the below:

```js
var p=[1,0,1,0];
var clubs=[[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical", ""],["Student Government", ""],["Tricorn", ""],["FBLA", ""]];
console.log(clubs.filter((a, i) =>p[i]==1).flat().filter((a) =>a ).map(a=>a.trim()).join(',<br>'));
```

Comment: I don't believe he can flatten the array previously, because he is using the `index` of the inner arrays in some way to control what to show.

Comment: The OP still wants commas in some instances, so if you add it back to the join, you seem to have a working answer.

Comment: @Shidersz, the .flat doesn't flatten the original array. It does flatten the array, but it returns the result for chaining, rather than changing the original array.

Comment: @computercarguy I know that, what I want to mean is that he the OP don't need to show all the values joined, he is filtering the inner arrays in some way too before generating the output string.

Comment: @Shiderz. Yeah I got your point. But OP did not mention what the condition is doing. I just saw the sample input and output and gave a solution for that.

Comment: @Shidersz, ah, I see that now.  However, the OP can still use this after getting the correct options into an array.  So, basically, he pushes clubs[h] into recClubs without the join, then once that loop is done, he can use this on recClubs.

Comment: @computercarguy Yea, that solution will fit.

Comment: @shiderz, or op can use the `index` parameter that `filter` takes and provide an additional condition like this. `clubs.flat().filter((a,i)=>a && pchoice[i] == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const clubs = [
    ["Fall Production"," Spring Musical", ""],
    ["Student Government", ""],
    ["Tricorn", ""],
    ["FBLA", ""]
];

// filter empty values of arrays of strings
const filteredClubs = clubs.map(arr => arr.filter(a => a));

// convert filteredClubs in a one level array
const oneLevelArrayClubs = filteredClubs.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(next));


// join them with what you wanted
const clubsString = oneLevelArrayClubs.join(', <br/>');
```

Comment: In testing this, I don't see how this works for the Question. If it was a one dimensional array it might work, but not with it being a 2D array.

Comment: You are right.
You must filter the arrays of strings, not the arrays of arrays. I took it for granted. I just improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) through the array and use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var clubs=[[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical", ""],["Student Government", ""],["Tricorn", ""],["FBLA", ""]]

let result = clubs.flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y))

console.log(result)
```

Then you can do another [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you want to add a line break and trim etc. If your data is cleaner however you can skip that step so you should try if possible to correct those empty spaces in your data etc.

`let result = clubs.flatMap(x => x.filter(y => y)).map(x => x.trim())`

**Note:** `Array.flat` and `Array.flatMap` they both **do not have support in IE** so you would need a polyfill

You can avoid that with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) / [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like so:

```js
var clubs=[[" Fall Production"," Spring Musical", ""],["Student Government", ""],["Tricorn", ""],["FBLA", ""]]

let result = clubs.map(x => x.filter(y => y)).reduce((r,c) => [...r,...c], [])

console.log(result)
```